# Multi-Threaded Wavetable Synthesizer clicks. Is this caused by torn reads?

Tags: multithreading, audio, signal-processing, waveform, synthesizer

I'm currently working on a very basic wavetable synthesizer. I'll try my best to give an understandable overview.

I have a *single* lookup-waveform with 4096 points, which is sampled by the audio thread. In general, however, a single oscillator has multiple waveforms, which can be morphed by a `position` parameter. For example, let's take two sine waves where the second one has half the period of the first one. When we play those back at `frequency = 440Hz` and `position = 0.5`, we would hear two equally loud tones at 440Hz and 880Hz. Here's [a link to the audio](https://clyp.it/4nx40qqy?token=adb6043b5045fe9897b275c9f269f010) (See Sidenote 2).

[image: Frequency spectrum of the 440Hz and 880Hz sine waves]

Due to performance reasons I generate the lookup table on another thread whenever the position parameter changes. And therein lies my problem. Even when I don't change the table position and just periodically generate my lookup table, I get weird, unpredictable glitches. Since the audio data in the table doesn't change in this case, I can only explain this by torn reads. Is that correct? And if so, how do I get around it? Do I use a double-buffer with an atomic pointer-swap after I finish generating the data?

[image: Same frequency spectrum, but with glitches]

Again, here's [the audio for this recording](https://clyp.it/wvnvhzji?token=7dd5fffe505ba0e47b5dcf60be08ce4b) (See Sidenote 2).
Also, some oscilloscope data:

[image: Oscilloscope Image where such a glitch is visible]

**Sidenote 1**: Populating my lookup table takes `~50,000ns` without optimizations and `~10,000ns` with optimizations. But the glitches seem to happen with the same probability.

**Sidenote 2**: The website I uploaded the audio to seems to have introduced some weird harmonics, which are not audible in my video. Just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! I accidentally set an old scanner position after generating my lookup table. If the latter took too long my position was basically reset to a few microseconds earlier, which explains the visual setback in the oscilloscope.

Comment: I tried to do that yesterday, but Stackoverflow said I have to wait two more days before I'm allowed to :)

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Done